# Mix-blend-mode working when applied to one element but not another

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I am using `mix-blend-mode` on css-generated content to create a multiplied background effect.

When I apply this generated element to an outer wrapper it has the intended effect:

```css
.standard-cover {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.standard-cover:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.image-wrap {
  line-height: 0;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.content-wrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 30;
  min-height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard-cover">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/nature" alt="Nature">
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>A title</h2>
      <p>A pagragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I apply it to an inner wrapper it does not:

```css
.standard-cover {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.image-wrap {
  line-height: 0;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.content-wrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 30;
  min-height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3.33%;
}
.content-wrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard-cover">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/nature" alt="Nature">
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>A title</h2>
      <p>A pagragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In both cases the actual css that applies the faux background color is identical:

```
.class:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

But in the first example it in fact applies the `mix-blend-mode` effect properly. In the second example it does not (despite inspectors confirming that the `mix-blend-mode` attribute is present and set to `multiply`).

Is there some nuance to the mix-blend-mode spec that I'm not understanding? Or am I missing some crucial something in my code?

Answer (score 3):

I achieved the same effect by applying the `mix-blend-mode: difference !important;` and `filter: invert(1) !important;` styles to the header element of my nav-bar, the nav-bar itself has a transparent background so it only finds of the difference of the child elements against the background.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about stacking context. In the first case, the pseudo element is applied to `.standard-cover` where there is the background so its a child element of it and `mix-blend-mode` will work correctly because both belong to the same stacking context. In the second case, you moved the pseudo element to `.content-wrap` and there is a `z-index` specified so now it belong to another stacking context and `mix-blend-mode` will no more have effect outside.

An easy solution is to remove the z-index from `.content-wrap` to avoid creating a stacking context and mix-blend-mode will work like intended:

```css
.standard-cover {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.image-wrap {
  line-height: 0;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.content-wrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  min-height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3.33%;
}
.content-wrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard-cover">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/nature" alt="Nature">
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>A title</h2>
      <p>A pagragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: Applying a blendmode other than normal to the element must establish a new stacking context [CSS21]. This group must **then be blended and composited with the stacking context that contains the element.** <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode)</sup>